# jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

can autocomplete check words in the middle of the string. If i wite "C" i can get "Core" but if i write "re" i will not get "Core"...

Comment: `ro` is not in `Core`.  Did you mean to write `or`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the option for contains.  Specifically, set 'matchContains: true'.  The [demo page](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/) provide the following example that uses 'matchContains':

```
$("#suggest14").autocomplete(cities, {
    matchContains: true,
    minChars: 0
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. You could see that for yourself in <60 seconds at [the demo page](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/). Type `n` into the `Single Bird` field.

Comment: sorry i didn't see this page. i use google and forget about this demo

Comment: @senzacionale: there's a link to the demo page _in the page your question links to_.